# How do I make sense of Bontrager Tire Models?

Tags: tire, terminology

Looking at different tires from Trek, they have names like T2, R3, AW1, but I can't find anywhere that decodes these names and tells me the difference between one or the other.

Comment: What do you need the information for? Bontrager is a OEM house brand for Trek and if you're buying replacement tires, you're better off buying a dedicated tire brand.

Comment: @ojs Bontrager actually make some very good tyres and their MTB tyres are very worthy for consideration when buying.  The 120tpi 'Team Issue' casings are one of the best around

Comment: @AndyP I think it's more that Bontrager brand has some nice tires, but they are more or less relabeled products from other manufacturers. It might be that in the US the relabeled version distributed by Trek is a good deal, in Europe not so much.

Comment: @ojs are you sure you aren't getting confused with another brand?  Bontrager tyres have their own R&D, and at least in their MTB tyre line feature unique tread patterns, and superior casings to most other brands.  Here in the UK (still part of Europe - for the moment), they are generally competitively priced and well thought of by anyone that tries them.

Comment: Here's an interesting read: https://bikerumor.com/2018/03/20/tire-tech-how-mountain-bike-tire-tread-is-designed-part-two-a-chat-with-bontrager/

Comment: Fair point, I'm more familiar with road products. At some point their top end tires were found to be extremely similar to Vittoria (which just happened to be the best thing commonly available at the time), but this was already some time ago. For some reason UK has been quite separate market before anyone even talked about Brexit.

Comment: Bontrager's tires definitely are *not* relabeled products, and some are seriously worthwhile tires tested at the world cup level. I work at a bike shop and have access to Trek's online training materials, I just wish there were an easy way to tell that AW3 is a road tire (what do the A and W stand for?) It doesn't seem intuitive that SE is for Enduro, while XR3 is Mountain bike, and when one tire is more expensive, I want to be able to easily tell customers what I'm asking them to pay more for.

Answer (score 1):

They are indicators of what product line Trek is placing each tire in. For example, R=road, AW=all weather, t=Touring, XR=cross road (or something like that, indicating smaller tread that is not too big for mixed road riding) G=gravel and so on. I would say that these prefixes don't really mean much, just choose a tire that is appropriate for the type of riding you will be doing.

Comment: How would you choose a tire that's appropriate without being guided by the prefixes? Clearly they must mean something.

Comment: Take a look at these 3 links. All different prefixes, but to my eyes very similar.
https://bit.ly/2lYnVo0  https://bit.ly/2kfxVZE  https://bit.ly/2kP55zz
(BTW, editing my original answer, it appears Trek uses the "T" to mean Touring, not Tread.)
So, can you use a "Hybrid" tire for touring? Road riding? How about for "Gravel" riding? I think you will find a lot of crossover in these lines.

Comment: Although the prefix means something, chances are the difference is much smaller than the marketing people will have us believe.

Comment: That is a fair point, but to my mind, there are some clear distinctions. There's clearly one group of mainly road tires, including the performance road and all weather ones. There's one group of hybrid bike and touring tires, and you could maybe lump the all weather tires in here also. The gravel and CX tires are pretty close in tread, and you can definitely use a gravel tire in a CX race, as well as vice versa. Those distinctions are clear. So, I guess I can discern some broad categories.

Comment: @Weiwen Ng, yeah,  the broad categories and distinctions are there, I just wouldn't want people to think something like "I have a cross bike, so should get cx tires for it" even if they are primarily using it to commute on dry pavement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to add links, since they will become broken eventually, but look at the Trek bicycle web site. (they own Bontrager) If you look through the tire section of the site, then filter for eg. road tires, and click on a specific tire, you'll see some specs on the tire, eg tpi, the weight etc